# Why can't I use cortana?

Tags: cortana

I'm using a Nokia 928 on Verizon. I have the most available updates so window 8.1 is the operating system. I have confirmed this so please don't ask. My region is United States. My language is English (United States). When I try to turn on Cortana it says Cortana is not available with my selected region and language. Any idea why my phone would think I have chose a region and language other what I described. I am also physically in the United States. Central Texas specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the speech and everything to En-Us.

Comment: also change the location to ON